# Show and hide AdMob banner with better performance?

Tags: android, admob

I'm programmming my own adroid app.
In this app I'm using OpenGL for all the 2D graphics.
I want to implement AdmMob banner ads to make some money ( hopefully ;) ). The banner is shown every time the player dies in the die-screen but not while the player is playing.

**The problem is:** As I integrated a test ad the app began to lag and it takes a
few more seconds to load the die-screen.

To load and hide the banner I use these two methods: (from: [The Google Developer site](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/games))

```
    private void showBanner() {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
    private void hideBanner() {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

**My question is**: Does anybody know if I can load the banner once at the start with:

> mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)

And show and hide the banner only with:

```
    private void showBanner() {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    private void hideBanner() {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

**???????**

Or is it against the Implementation guidance?

PS: This method would be faster because it doesn't has to load a new ad every time the player dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use to pause/resume adView. So, I would update your code as follows:

```
private void showBanner() {
    mAdView.resume();
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
private void hideBanner() {
    mAdView.pause();
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I have being used this code in my app (available in GooglePlay) and I never received a notification for doing something wrong. So, I think there's no problem.

HOWEVER,

Checking this google developer website, it seems that is not even needed. So, maybe, your hide code should be OK.. just showBanner that should be updated to request a new one...

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/games

**During gameplay, you'll want to hide the ad. This can be done by calling this hideBanner method:**

```
private void hideBanner() {
    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**When the game is over, call the showBanner method again to refresh the ad and make it visible.**

```
private void showBanner() {
  adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
      .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try the methods with pause and resume. I already got my methods from the developer website and my problem was that it took to long to load the banner every time again ( adView.loadAd () ). But i think it'll be better just with pause and resume